# How to throw exception in JUnit Test for SSLContextBuilder.create().loadTrustMaterial?

Tags: java, aem, junit5

I have tried to write junit tests for the following piece of code but was unable to throw the exception in the test case.
The following is the implementation:

```
public static HttpClientBuilder createTrustAllHttpClientBuilder() {
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                    .create()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true) <= How to throw exception for this line
                    .build();
    }
    catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

The following is my junit Test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SSLContextBuilder.class})
public class testClass {

     public void testCase() {
           SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = mock(SSLContextBuilder.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
           PowerMockito.mockStatic(SSLContextBuilder.class);
           PowerMockito.when(SSLContextBuilder.create()).thenReturn(sslContextBuilder);
           PowerMockito.when(sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true)).thenThrow(new NoSuchAlgorithmException());
     }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any form of help or sharing of knowledge if you have encountered the following issue previously. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have a mock, you can use `thenThrow` instead of `thenReturn` to have your mock throw the exception.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html

Comment: I have written the thenThrow as shown in the code snippet above but it was not throwing the excetion